# Some items not showing up in grouped view of document libary

Tags: document-library

I have a document library that contains several hundred articles I've written that were published in a couple of different magazines. I've added some custom fields to, among other things, identify the magazine and indicate the type of each article.

I created a view of the document library that's grouped, first, on the magazine and then on the type of article and put an app part set to that view on a page of my public website. When I'm logged in to Office 365 and looking at my site that way, I see both publications at the top level. However, when I'm not logged in and look at my site as the general public sees it, only the first magazine shows up. (Here's a link to the page: http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/publications/articles.)

I'm mostly sure (though not 100%) this was right when I made the site public a month or so back. Any ideas whether this is something I've messed up or a bug? Any ideas?

Tamar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was user error (that is, me). I hadn't checked the relevant files in.